# How do I access multiple fields in a JPA query?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I have a JPA query of the form:

```
SELECT category, count(*) AS c FROM ...
```

I know that if the query just returns a single column I can do something like:

```
List<Article> articles = query.getResultList();
```

However, how do I access the results when there are 2 or more columns as in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out section 14.6 here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

it will return a List of Object[] if you select more than one column, but dont get the actual entity.