# How to SELECT in SQL or JPQL each line which have the last record with a specific String?

Tags: sql, jpql

I want to select the person (here John) whose last statusname is first? I don't know how to do it.

Table PERSON

```
id |name |status
1 | john | 1
2 | fritz | 1
3 | fritz| 2
```

Table STATUS

```
id |statusname
1 | first
2 | second
3 | third
```

I have tried the following request in JPQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Person p INNER JOIN p.status WHERE status.statusname="first";
```

I get all the three lines in my results. What's wrong please?

Comment: hey have a look at this link maybe it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197266/how-do-i-access-multiple-fields-in-a-jpa-query

Comment: what do yo mean with *last* statusname? There are two persons with the statusname **first**.

Comment: A person could have in first status "first" and if he did some actions status change to "second". Last status for this one is "second".

Comment: Yes here two person have the status first

Comment: Is **first** always the first status and does *last first* mean, that the person got only one status, or can a status may it be **first** or **second** get deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If there is always a **first** status and this status can not be deleted then you get your *last* **first** with

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Person p 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(status) = 1
```

A generic solution could look like this

```
SELECT name
FROM Person 
GROUP BY name
HAVING MAX(status) = (
   SELECT id FROM status WHERE statusname = 'first'
);
```

There you can replace 'first' with a host variable holding your statusname.

Comment: thanks for answering. Your request is seems good. I think it will work. I will test soon.To select "second" status i have to have HAVING COUNT(status) = 2. I don't know if i could make it generic. I don't know if it is possible to pass just the status because i my request user will enter status

Comment: I added a generic solution.